# Files-app stopped working with Samba-server again

Tags: iphone, ios, smb, files.app

This used to work for me, but now trying to browse the same server (smb://servername) throws an "Unknown Error" popup first, then shows a blank list.

The `smb.conf` hasn't changed in months, here is the `[global]`-section, as output by `testparm`:

```
[global]
        client min protocol = NT1
        dns proxy = No
        lanman auth = Yes
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 50
        ntlm auth = ntlmv1-permitted
        security = USER
        server min protocol = NT1
        server string = Meow Samba Server
        socket options = SO_RCVBUF=8192 SO_SNDBUF=8192
        unix charset = koi8-u
        workgroup = Meow
        fruit:copyfile = yes
        idmap config * : backend = tdb
        hosts allow = 192.168.1. 127.
        vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr zfsacl
```

There are no obvious errors in the server-side logs, the login works, my account's Unix-groups are enumerated... Upgrading Samba -- from 4.13.8 to 4.13.14 and then to 4.13.15 -- didn't help.

Any clues? Do I need to enable some more of the `vfs objects`, perhaps?

Comment: maybe too much folders/files, or some symbol in folder/file name?

Comment: There are only 9 shares (including `[printers]`) and all of their names are in ASCII... But I tried commenting out the `unix charset` line -- it didn't help, so I put it back.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, simply *rebooting* the iPhone resolved this problem... Nothing to do with `smb.conf`, after all.

Sigh -- is not quality, what we're, supposedly, paying for, when choosing Apple?

Comment: Opening SMB share in the iPhone Files app gives `folder is empty` message. Rebooting the iPhone indeed resolves the problem. Removing the SMB share and adding it back in the Files app fixes it too. Stops working after network connectivity issues.